# Edit custom fields in sales order ,status invoiced ax 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have added 2 custom fields in sales table,descriptive ones, and they appear on the header of sales order.As far as I have read there is now way to edit  the standard fields after invoicing.Is there any possibility to edit the custom ones after posting the invoice.

Comment: The short answer is "Yes"

Answer (score 1):

Whether it is allowed to edit the sales order is a sales paramter. Just allow edit after invoicing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to do that, for this reason AX standard does not allow this in document to be posted. But depending on the requirement of course it can be done.

You need to create your fields and add the logic to save these values.

For example if you call method `doUpdate()` of the table save your values without performing any validation.